# Extending conduit/cable for new induction cooktop

Tags: electrical, kitchens

Just looking for a double check on something I think shouldn't be an issue.

I currently have an old electric drop-in cooktop, and I'm looking to replace it with a new induction unit. The old unit has the MC cable run to a junction box in the base cabinet next to where the cutout actually is. The new unit fits in the old cutout, but the MC cable supplied with the unit is too short to reach the original junction box.

The cable on the new unit doesn't look modular, so I don't think there is an easy easy to replace it. My plan was just to install a new surface mount junction box in the base cabinet under the cooktop, splice the supplied cable to a longer MC cable that reaches the original junction box (appropriate connectors, of course).

Any foreseeable issues with that?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, making a splice in a junction box to extend a cable is valid.

All junction boxes must remain "accessible" without tools (i.e. not buried inside a wall) but it sounds like you're not planning to violate that.

Pay attention to box fill rules. You'll need a fairly large junction box to accommodate the wire sizes involved in feeding an induction cooktop. Plan to get a box bigger than whatever the box fill calculation says is the bare minimum, because while filling a box to the limit is legal, it will not be easy to work with.